# Curl SMTP TLS ERROR

Tags: c, curl

when i run the curl command than it work.

but when i run example in curl  **smtp-tls.c** than i getting error.

here is output.

**output :**

```
  Rebuilt URL to: smtp.office365.com:587/
  * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  *   Trying 111.221.114.166...

  * Connected to smtp.office365.com (111.221.114.166) port 587 (#0)

  < 220 HKNPR03CA002.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 13 
  Oct 2014 11:00:16 +0000

  > EHLO bhagirath-OptiPlex-390

  < 250-HKNPR03CA002.outlook.office365.com Hello [14.140.152.42]

  < 250-SIZE 78643200

  < 250-PIPELINING

  < 250-DSN

  < 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

  < 250-STARTTLS

  < 250-8BITMIME

  < 250-BINARYMIME

  < 250 CHUNKING

  > MAIL FROM:<abc@xyz.com>

  < 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

  * MAIL failed: 530

  > QUIT

  * response reading failed

  * Closing connection 0

  curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed sending data to the peer
```

please help to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated` seems obvious enough.

Comment: what is mean , i pass right email & password

Answer (score -1):

You must have not set a username \ password for the smtp server.
You need to do the following:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "user");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "secret");
```

See documentation:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html